# Linking Firebase Analytics to Google Analytics 4 - Old data lost

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

We have a React Native app that has been logging to Firebase Analytics for over a year.
In December, Google encouraged us to start using GA4, so we created a property and linked our existing Firebase Analytics data to it. GA4 is working as expected.
However, we no longer see to our analytics data prior to the date we linked to GA4 - not even in the Firebase Console - it only shows data from the date we linked onwards.
Something I am missing, or any help on how to 'find' the pre-GA4 data in the Firebase Console?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any solution?